# Looking for an old Japanese UFO film

Tags: story-identification, movie, ufos

I am looking for an old Japanese UFO film in which a little girl named KAYO comes to Earth in a UFO which looked like a golden egg. Then a family takes her to their home and she grows up with them. One day the aliens come to Earth and take her back to space and ...

Comment: Do you have any time-frame in mind? Is this live-action or animated? Also: and...?

Comment: @Shisa "... and they all lived happily ever after", I'm assuming

Answer (score 4):

"[Princess From The Moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_from_the_Moon)" (1987)

Per Wikipedia:

> One day wood cutter Taketori-no-Miyatsuko (Toshiro Mifune) discovers a
>   baby girl while he's out in the forest visiting his daughter's grave.
>   Not wanting to leave the infant to die and because of her resemblance
>   to his dead daughter, he takes the child home with him- only to
>   discover that the child grows at an extraordinarily fast rate.
>   **Incredibly beautiful, the now grown child Kaya** (Yasuko Sawaguchi) attracts the attention of everyone around her, including the land's
>   Emperor. Unwilling to accept their advances, Kaya gives the men a list
>   of increasingly difficult tasks. By the film's end Kaya returns to
>   outer-space by way of a space ship.

[image: Movie Poster]

[image: Space Egg]

Comment: my good friends,
that was the very exact name of the movie. thank you very much for your help.